# jQuery returns empty data

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have jQuery function to send data to another PHP file.

```
$(function() {
  $(".button").click(function() {
    var ButtonValue = $(this).attr('value');
    $.ajax({
      url: 'content_articles.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        mark: ButtonValue
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The `ButtonValue` variable is right. But it is empty on next page.

```
$rowid=$_POST['mark'];
```

Comment: Is the second code example (I.e. `$rowid=$_POST['mark'];`) the _complete_ contents of *content_articles.php*?

Comment: What you see in console? any errors? and how do you know `$_POST['mark']` is empty? please share more code of your `content_articles.php` file

Answer (score -2):

Did you do json decoding in your php?

It should be like

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

And then you can use

```
$_POST['mark']
```

Comment: And why does he need to do **json decoding**?